# HTML OnClick image source changes in web, but not mobile

Tags: html, wordpress, mobile, onclick, elementor

I'm working in Wordpress with the Elementor block builder and I'm trying to have a .gif image switch sources to another .gif image. The OnClick event I have works perfectly fine via web, but not mobile. I've searched endlessly and have made sure another element is not blocking the touch event, added OnTouch, etc but to no avail.

```
<img src="https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Loop1.gif"
onClick="this.src='https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Loop1D.gif'">
```

Comment: @luekbaja whoops, never mind. I posted the comment to the wrong topic. Sorry.

Comment: It is because you are touching not clicking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `onClick` to `onclick`:

```html
<img src="https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Loop1.gif"
onclick="this.src='https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Loop1D.gif'">
```

HTML attributes are case sensitive.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. The only thing now is that the .gif repeats slightly upon being clicked.